# How to open (not only start) virtual machine from CLI

Tags: debian, command-line, kvm, qemu, virsh

Installed qemu kvm, created Windows10 vm and I can start and open it from the GUI. Exited (quit, not close) KVM GUI.

```
# virsh list --all
 Id   Name    State
------------------------
 -    win10   shut off
```

Then I ran:

```
    # virsh start win10 
    Domain win10 started
```

Again listed status:

```
virsh list --all
 Id   Name    State
-----------------------
 3    win10   running
```

It's running.

Host system is Debian 10.

How to open it from CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad.

Forgot about remote-viewer.

I opened it with

```
remote-viewer spice://127.0.0.1:5900
```

Comment: How do you know the local IP of the virtual machine?

Comment: @phdstudent what do you mean by "local IP of vm"? It's on localhost (standard default IP of localhost is 127.0.0.1 ), and standard remote-viewer port is 5900 ("common port"). In above example, the SPICE protocol is used.